# How to Change size of split screen emacs windows?

Tags: window, customize

If I have Emacs split horizontally and on top I'm editing elisp code and on the bottom I am in the shell. By default, Emacs makes the two windows equal in size, but I'd like the shell buffer smaller. I was wondering how I could do that.

Original question asked by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615550/steve) on SO: [How to Change size of split screen emacs windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows)

Comment: Are we intentionally *duplicating* questions from SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows

Comment: @phils, No I was not. But I will make a link to the post. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: beyond that, that one was a little bit too easy :)

Comment: Gee, great edit @King. Now this question has become *really* different from the one you copied...

Comment: Sorry for all the uproar, but I find this question interesting. There are so customization options. And this is by far one of the most serviceable options in Emacs.

Comment: it make me think that, the emacs related questions on SO should be migrated. It will have avoided the (tiny) uproar

Comment: See http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4/184 .

Answer (score 55, accepted):

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> (`shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer`) to shrink a window to fit its content.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> (`balance-windows`) to make windows the same heights and widths.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> (`enlarge-window`) to increase height by 1 line, or the prefix arg value. A negative arg shrinks the window. Example: <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> (`shrink-window-horizontally`)

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> (`enlarge-window-horizontally`)

Comment: **+1** for the shrinking command. I was looking for the way to shrink by a single line. What is `C-u`?

Comment: @Vass `C-u` begin a numeric argument for the following command. If you want to increase 5 times, instead of typing, 5 times, the same command, you type `C-u 5` `C-x ^`

Comment: It's also worth noting that `C-u` default value is 4, meaning that `C-u C-x ^` will do the same as `C-u 4 C-x ^`.

Answer (score 13):

I would also recommend checking out either the `windresize` package from [ELPA](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/), or the `windsize` package from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/).

With `windresize`, you can do `M-x windresize` and then use the arrow keys to move window borders easily, hitting ENTER when you're done.

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> (`enlarge-window`) in the upper window to make it larger (and thus make the lower window smaller).

Using the mouse, you can also drag the modeline of the upper window to resize it.

Comment: great idea to make another window smaller by enlarging the one above it!

Answer (score 1):

Also note that just like in a window system, you can use the mouse with xterm-mouse-mode to drag the window divider.

Note that this seems to sometimes depend a bit on the actual xterm or xterm-like program, and iirc in older Emacsen it wasn't reliable past about the 100th column unless you played with the TERM environment variable a bit, but in my Emacs 24.2.1 it works fine with emacs -nw -q (ie. totally ignoring my .emacs and manually enabling xterm-mouse-mode with `M-x xterm-mouse-mode`)

*Update:* FYI for completeness I'll point out this also works for vertical dividers (ie. when you have split with `C-x 3`)

Answer (score 1):

I've ever written a simple minor-mode (for my personal usage) to interactively `resize-frame`. I think this should be convenient.

https://gist.github.com/kuanyui/65a408d393871048771c

`M-x resize-frame`to enable the `resize-frame` minor-mode:

1. Press `arrow keys` to adjust size horizontally/vertically.
2. Press any other keys to disable.