# With side-by-side windows how to slide the middle vertical bar?

Tags: window-splitting

I often have two buffers open side by side and I'd like to be able to slide the central vertical bar to the left or to the right, in order to make either buffer wider or narrower.

Is this supported in emacs 26.3?

Here's what I get:

[image]

The vertical bar in the middle won't move.

I looked at [this other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows), but `M-x xterm-mouse-mode` didn't help.

Comment: You can drag the vertical split with your mouse.

Comment: It won't move. That's what I was used to on a different machine, where I perhaps ran a different version of emacs. I no longer have access to that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag the vertical split with your mouse. And you can use `C-x }` and `C-x {` to enlarge or shrink a window horizontally. And you can use `C-x ^` to enlarge a window vertically.

Comment: Thanks for the commands!
As silly as it sounds, I can't drag it with my mouse. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Maybe it is only draggable at the bottom between th blue and gray bar?

Comment: Yes, try what @JohnKitchin suggested. That's a known situation for some platforms, I believe. And try the key bindings I mentioned - they should work whether or not the divider is mouse draggable. If they too don't work then that should tell us something else.

Comment: @JohnKitchin YES, that was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Drew the key bindings work too, thanks!